# Magento - CSS is not loading in magento

Tags: php, css, magento

I have installed Magento on live server. But the problem is that its not loading css. I have double checked .htaccess file but There is nothing any issue in it. I have given full access permission on Var, Media & app/etc folder.

Please let me know that what is the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Alex S.

Comment: You said the media directory permissions were fine. What about under it? What are the permissions on media/js, media/css, and media/css_secure?

Same thing with under var. What are the permissions on var/cache and var/full_page_cache?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is due to .htaccess file. In my project there is an `.htaccess` file in `/skin` folder with following content:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

I have removed this file and it works fine.

Comment: Good answer. Many overlook nested .htaccess files and only look at the root.

Answer (score 0):

View the source of your page and click the css links, if it is pointed correctly it should bring you to the css page.

Comment: Hi, Thank for your reply. But i am getting 500 Internal server error. Let me know what i have to do                                    Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, that is a file permission error. What is the current file permission?

Comment: I have checked my file permission and its 777.

Comment: You should try this  set 755 for magento folder and index.php. The 0644 for files.

Comment: I have done with this changes,but getting same issue. I think, May be the issue of .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0):

For htaccess, make sure the RewriteBase / is uncommented. So from #RewriteBase / to RewriteBase /. Check the error log if possible. And, another thing i remember, you may need to clear your cache and tmp folder too. Do this first, clear cache and tmp folder.

Comment: Did you clear the cache and tmp folder? And also, check the error log.

Comment: Yes i have checked it... even also check the error log. There is nothing in this error log. Thanks

Comment: Read this, http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3566/ , that might help

Comment: @user1149244 link seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

At the time of installation magento asked about secure URL and unsecure URL. These urls must be changed when we change our server. If you couldn't access `admin` >> `system` >> `configuration`

Then you could change it from database. Find in table

> dbprefix . core_config_data

change path

`web/unsecure/base_url` to your new domain name
`web/secure/base_url` to your new domain name

**Note** : Please don't forget to put forward trailing slash at last. like: www.newdomain.com`/`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed base_url path in Mysql

```
as : web/secure/base_url = http://example.com/
```

Must mention `/` at the end of `.com`
Then clear session and cache.
Then restart MySQL and Apache2.
Similar for `unsecure/base_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest follow step by step.

There is 2 case:

1) You can see your CCS **directly** from URL, so browser load it by direct URL, example: `http://your-magento/skin/frontend/your-package/your-theme/css/styles.css`, so in this case you should check points connected with Magento:

- Check/Correct Base URL from config or DB
- Clear Cache
- Clear Sessions
- Check Configurations

2) If your CSS is not loading by direct URL. So in this case **it is not connected with Magento** at all.
In this case you should check follwoing points:

- Check files and folders permissions
- Check rewrite rules and modules
- Server Log files to find error
- Check .htaccess for existance and for correctness.
- **Important**, check all .htaccess files in all sub-folders.

In my case, I differed this 2 cases and start seaching my issue in second case.

I found `.htaccess` in folder `/skin/frontend/your-package/your-theme/`
The content was following:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Remove this file and your CSS files will be loaded.
I don't know how this file was created, I don't have file like this in parent theme. I think Magento is automatically created it. Be attentive and follow changes with GIT.

Answer (score -1):

Check permissions for the folders like app/etc, var, media folders. Try to give 777 permissions to those folders. Recently I have faced the same problem and I tried with this. Then my site works fine.

Comment: Please don't. If changing the permissions on your folders to 777, your server is configured incorrectly. Look into using some kind of SuExec module.